# Searching for substrings with an in operator out of a list of words in Python

Tags: python, list, search, substring

I am attempting to run a program that will find a new value for A if there is a period contained within a certain index range of it. The problem is, in order to determine the domain of the search, it is necessary to have the words separated within a list, such as this ('A', 'B.', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'). The object is to get the program to find the first A, search the smaller list ('A B. C D') for a '.' and, if it finds one, to assign the variable to the next instance of A. All of the code works so far, except for finding the '.' with an in operator, because it is treating it as 'B.' . This would not work in application, as 'B' wil not be known.

Is there any way to search for a '.' even if it appears next to unknown text? I have attempted using regular expressions, but it is not responding well. This is probably a result of an error on my part.

```
words = 'A B. C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G'
corpus = words.split()
index_A = corpus.index('A')
while '.' in corpus[index_A : index_A + 3]:
  # This does not seem to be picking up the '.' in 'b.' in isolation.  It will find
  # 'B.' but not '.' from corpus.
  index_A = corpus.index('A', index_A+1)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What is "unknown text" and why wouldn't `"." in foo` work? :) I think some example code or input and expected output could help a bit.

Comment: I think he wants to move said str object to the parent object if it's a list?

Comment: @jbcurtin: Hmm... yeah. What I don't quite understand is the ('A B. C D') list, is this the result of find the period and moving data?

Comment: Aye, I think he's trying to do three things in one. Find A, check if A has '.' - if true, move A contents to parent? Michael, could you try breaking up the problem into more pieces?

Comment: That was the problem, actually. I was looking for a value of A that does not occur near a '.'.(within 4 places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks for the '.' at the end of an entry.

```
  words = 'A B. C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G'
  corpus = words.split()
   for item in corpus:
    if item.endswith('.'):
     #logic
```

Comment: This seems to work the same as the for loop, but is easier to read. I am just surprised that something so specific is built in. I guess I should have check the list of BIFs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for regex here, but regex would work.  Remember to escape the dot as it is special.  Then remember to use a raw string to escape your escape. :)

The problem with your while loop is you're looking for an item exactly equal to "." in that slice, rather than an item in that slice that contains ".".  Change to checking inside each item:

```
while any("." in x for x in corpus[index_A : index_A + 3]):
```

Comment: Was just typing up the same thing.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure I understand your response. When it comes to the other comments, I apologize for not putting the code. Here it is. words= ('A B. C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F G') corpus= words.split()                                         index_A= corpus.index('A')                                           while '.' in corpus[index_A : index_A + 3]: # This line does not seem to be picking up the '.' in 'b.' in isolation, it will find 'B.' but not '.' from corpus                                    index_A= corpus.index('A', index_A+1)

Comment: @MichaelRauh: Moved that code to the question; hope I've understood you correctly.

Comment: You have understood. This should work very well. I thought it was looking too specifically, but a for loop didn't occur to me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be parsing sentences here. Have you considered using the [Natural Language Toolkit for Python](http://www.nltk.org/) to do this?

Comment: I actually did not know this existed. Thank you for pointing this out!